# magento 2 override the default "luma" fotorama-item product detail page slider .phtml

Tags: magento2, product-images, slider, luma-theme

I want to change the fotorama-item and palace the custom zoom functionality on the product detail page. I am using the default "luma" theme not my custom theme.

I have gone to the admin panel and Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront and it's using the below file:

`E:/xampp/htdocs/learnmagento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

So, just want to remove fotorama and palace the below example when we hover on the image.

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

I want to use the Inner Zoom.

Anybody can help me how I can palace the Inner Zoom functionality when user hove on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use zoom functionality within (Inner Zoom) the Image,

```
\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml
```

You can enable the magnifier ‘true’ as [referenced](http://www.daffodilsw.com/blog/magento-2-0-product-image-gallery-settings/),

```
<var name="magnifier">
<var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var> <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
<var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
<var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
<var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
<var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
<var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that activates zoom (hover/click) -->
<var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (zoom) (true/false) -->
</var>
```

Recommended to change the changes by creating custom theme.

Comment: Can I override the `view.xml` using this file structure `E:\xampp\htdocs\learnmagento\app\design\frontend\Magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml` ? Beacuse I have no any custom theme yet.

Comment: Thank you Kirsh, it's working fine if we enable the magnifier from  `view.xml`. Thanks for your help !!!!